# Inkscape: fill object without filling inner object

Tags: inkscape

I have this object (not grouped) :

[image]

This is what I want (after selecting a 'fill' color):

[image]

But I always get this:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cut off the inner objects from the outer object, i.e. to make a *difference*
(*Path → Difference*) of the outer object and inner objects, then you will fill only what you want.

To reach it:

1. Move your outer object to the bottom (*Object → Lower to Bottom*).
   (Because the difference cut off the higher object from the lower one.)
2. Select it and select one of the 3 inner objects.
3. Make a difference of them (*Path → Difference*, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>).
4. Repeat points 2 and 3 with other 2 inner objects.

Done. Now you may fill it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! For newbie users: selecting all three inner objects didn't work. Also, I made the selection by clicking the outer object then holding the shift key, and clicking one of the inner objects.

Comment: @Wolf359 If you select all three inner objects, and first do Path > Combine, then you can select the outer shape, and the inner combined shape and do the Difference operation, and it will work in just one step.

Comment: @Wolf359, you're welcome. Another approach is to first group inner 3 objects and then make the difference only once.

Answer (score 2):

You started with 4 shapes, each with a single path.  Select them all and combine into a single shape with 4 sub-paths.

[image]

You want the interior sub-paths to create holes in the shape.  If the holes are closed, use the node tool to select all the sub-path nodes then reverse the path direction.

[image]